# Envió de información por socket

Tags: java, socket

tengo una aplicacion la cual mediante el uso de una **API** se hace la lectura de unos eventos ,  la cual con la ayuda de una manejador de eventos del propio API es donde capturamos la información provenientes de cada evento. Una vez hecho ese tratamiento , la información es enviado por socket hacia otro proceso, la cual toma el papel de servidor.
A continuación el fragmento de código , donde hacemos una nueva instancia cada vez que recibimos un evento.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ccvox.statistic.receive;

import com.ccvox.statistic.main.Main;
import com.ccvox.statistic.util.Lector;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author op_lvidalv
 */
public class SendMessageInfo {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProcessorEventInfo.class.getName());

    static {
        LOGGER.addHandler(Main.getFileHandler());
    }

    //public static int conexiones = 0;
    public synchronized void envio(String cadena) {
        //boolean retorno = false;
        System.out.println("Enviando:" + cadena);
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(Lector.IP_DISPLAY, Lector.PUERTO_DISPLAY);

            if (socket == null) {
                envio(cadena);
                return;
            }
            socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            out.println(cadena);

            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }

            if (socket != null) {
                socket.close();
            }

            out = null;
            socket = null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Esta es la excepcion que me sale , apesar de cerrar la conexion cada  vez que envio la informacion. Inclusive sale otra excepciones como si la conexion o direccion ip ya existiese "Address already in use".

> GRAVE: null java.net.ConnectException: ConexiÃ³n rehusada
>
> ```
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>
>     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
>
>     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
>
>     at com.ccvox.statistic.receive.SendMessageInfo.envio(SendMessageInfo.java:32)
>
>     at com.ccvox.statistic.receive.ProcessorEventInfo.run(ProcessorEventInfo.java:158)
>
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Mi pregunta es como puedo tratar estas excepciones o a mejorar, o si me falta alguna configuración para tratar las múltiples conexiones que se realiza.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que yo haría sería dividir la `IOException` en dos grupos catch diferentes, para asignar acciones a cada grupo.
De este modo, pondría un catch delante de la `IOException` para tratar dicha excepción, así:

```
   try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(Lector.IP_DISPLAY, Lector.PUERTO_DISPLAY);

        if (socket == null) {
            envio(cadena);
            return;
        }
        socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        out.println(cadena);

        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }

        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }

        out = null;
        socket = null;

    } catch (ConnectException cx) {
        // Aquí tratas la excepción, por ejemplo volver a intentar conectar.
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```